# Autowiring issue with JUnit in a Spring Data JPA environment

Tags: spring, jpa, junit, autowired

i have issues with @autowired in my unit tests. 
here are the relevant classes and xml files:

**The Service Class:**

```
@Service(value = "statusService")
public class StatusService implements DefaultService<Status> {

  @Autowired(required = true)
  private StatusRepository statusRepository;

  public void save(Status value) {
    statusRepository.save(value);

  }
}
```

**The Interface:**

```
public interface DefaultService<T> {
  @Transactional
  void save(T value);

}
```

(i also tested a non generic interface, but the result was the same.)

**The Test Class:**

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"**/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml", "**/WEB-INF/hibernate-context.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class StatusServiceTest 
{
    @Autowired
    private StatusService statusService;

    @Test
    public void test() 
    {
        Status s = new Status();
        s.setDescription("desc");
        s.setStatus("status");

        statusService.save(s);
    }
}
```

**The Application Context:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"           
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">


    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
     For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="at.jba.ticketbox" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="at.jba.ticketbox.repositories" />

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
    Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <!-- Load Hibernate related configuration -->
    <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />

</beans>
```

**The Hibernate-Context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            ">

    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />

    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

    <!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
    <!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html -->                           
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html -->
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html -->
<!--    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
                 p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
                 p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
                 p:packagesToScan="at.jba.ticketbox"/>   -->

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
                p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driver}"
                p:url="${jdbc.url}"
                p:username="${jdbc.username}"
                p:password="${jdbc.password}"
                />


    <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" 
                p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

      <!-- JPA Entity Manager Factory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
          p:persistenceXmlLocation="META-INF/persistence.xml" 
          p:persistenceUnitName="springJpaPersistenceUnit_TEST" />          


    <!-- bean post-processor for JPA annotations -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

**and the stack trace:**

```
INFO : org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [class at.jba.ticketbox.service.interfaces.DefaultServiceTest]: using defaults.
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@63afe611: startup date [Tue Mar 13 15:19:44 CET 2012]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5543bd5c: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@4ad70ab0] to prepare test instance [at.jba.ticketbox.service.interfaces.DefaultServiceTest@6bfecf32]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'at.jba.ticketbox.service.interfaces.DefaultServiceTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private at.jba.ticketbox.service.StatusService at.jba.ticketbox.service.interfaces.DefaultServiceTest.sr; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [at.jba.ticketbox.service.StatusService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private at.jba.ticketbox.service.StatusService at.jba.ticketbox.service.interfaces.DefaultServiceTest.sr; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [at.jba.ticketbox.service.StatusService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [at.jba.ticketbox.service.StatusService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 28 more
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@63afe611: startup date [Tue Mar 13 15:19:44 CET 2012]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5543bd5c: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
```

i tried to autowire the interface (the generic one too) instead of the Service Class, cause i´ve read that there probably are issues.
i tried it with an @Resource, same stacktrace
i tried writting a non generic interface
...

i find it strange that the, application runs perfectly on an tomcat server as a web application. no problems there saving and deleting Objects. I still don´t understand why the tests aren´t working.
plz help ;) thx

Comment: Rather than posting what seems to be nearly ***ALL*** of your code, could you please slim it down to a minimal example that still exhibits the problem?

Comment: the two classes and one interface are fairly small but ok i´ll remove some of the methods. but how should i trim down the xml files when i don´t know what is wrong with them?! i easily could leave out important details

Answer (score 2):

By default, `locations` parameter of `@ContextConfiguration` annotation is assuming *classpath:* protocol, so you need to explicitly specify *file:* protocol when loading files not in the classpath, e.g. context located within WEB-INF folder:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={
    "file:**/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml", "file:**/WEB-INF/hibernate-context.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class StatusServiceTest 
  ...
```

Comment: So close, deleting my answer on WEB-INF being hidden.

Comment: thx for the suggestion. but in the meanwhile i did set up a new configuration setup only for tests in the src/test/recources folder with only a applicationContext.xml and a persistence.xml in the meta-inf folder. this was suggested by dardo before your answer ;) the issue is still remaining.

Comment: but i tried your suggestions with the "file:".. in the "old" version. same error... :(

Comment: ah f*** i had e spelling mistake.. the "file:" version works. :) thx